# c++ debugging in vis studio 2008, how to break when a variable becomes zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I can detect when a variable **changes**, but it changes so often that its no use - what I want is to detect the moment that a variable **becomes zero**.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible in Visual Studio.  Visual Studio supports a number of debugging features in that particular area but I don't think you can combine them into a feature to get what you want

- Data Changing Breakpoints: break when a value changes (only supported in native C++)
- Conditionally breakpoints: break when the IP crosses the breakpoint and a particular condition is satisfied.

What you could do though is wrap all writes to your variable into a setter function.  Then use a conditional breakpoint to break when the value changes to 0.  I think this is the closest you're going to get to the feature you want.

Comment: Thanks very much.. 
By the way, what does IP stand for?

Comment: IP = Instruction Pointer.  Essentially the line of code currently executing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of these debuggers

1 - http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx

2 - The Good Old SoftICE, if you can find it anywhere

3 - http://www.sysersoft.com/updatelog.html

Also check new version OllyDbg (it says it supports hardware breakpoints)

Comment: Syser Win32 Debugger seems to have hardware breakpoints, I did not try but it is free...

Comment: It is not free. It is a discontinued product. You should ask Compuware about it...